# Java Arrays and constructors

Tags: java

I am trying to make an object that has int in parameters, thats sends the value to another class, sets the value of the int to a private int in a constructor of another class and using the private int to set the size of an array, but i dosnt work... Does anyone know why? Below is an example of what i mean, i want to set the arrays size to 10.

```
main class: Car bmw = new Car(10);

Car class: public Car (int x)
              { y = x;}
private int y;
private String[] carArray= new String[y];
```

Comment: Move the initialization to the constructor.

Comment: Also please post the full code and the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code: `private String[] carArray= new String[y];` will be executed *before* the constuctor body. In your case `y` will still be 0 (that's the default for primitive fields) which results in an array of length 0 being created.

Thus you'll have to do it like that:

```
public Car (int x) { 
  y = x;
  carArray= new String[y];
}
```

Basically the call order is:

- super class' initializer block/constructor (if there are any)
- this class' initializer block
- this class' constructor

Example: assume we have `class Car extends Vehicle`.

If you call `new Car(10)` the call order *might* look like this (assuming there are no calls to other constructors:

- `Vehicle` initializer block
- `Vehicle` constructor
- `Car` initializer block
- `Car` constructor

An "initializer block" consists of everything that's in the class body but not part of a method (there actually are 2 initializer blocks: a static one and an instance one, the static one can be identified by the `static` keyword).

Comment: Ow ok I understand now, thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

instead initialize the array in the constructor

```
   main class: Car bmw = new Car(10);
           private int y;
         private String[] carArray=null;
     Car class: public Car (int x)
          { y = x;
           carArray= new String[y];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the Array inside your constructor:

```
public Car (int x) { 
    y = x;
    carArray= new String[x];
}
```